# add data at runtime in multiple rows in QTP/UFT

Tags: datatable, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I would like to add data at runtime in multiple rows but instead it creates a new column and add data to that. I've used below code.

```
For i = 1 To 2 Step 1
datatable.SetCurrentRow(i)  

Dim f_name,l_name
f_name=Datatable.Value("todayDate","date") + Datatable.Value("MonthName","date")
l_name=datatable.Value("This_Year","date")

Datatable.AddSheet("Emp_name").AddParameter"Emp_first_Name",f_name
Datatable.AddSheet("Emp_name").AddParameter"EMP_Last_Name",l_name

Next
```

Comment: have you tried with `Datatable.Value("Emp_first_Name","Emp_name") =f_name` and `Datatable.Value("Emp_Last_Name","Emp_name") =l_name`?

Answer (score 1):

AddParameter will add a new parameter each time - that's why you're seeing duplicate columns.

There's lots of ways around this - one way is to set up your table+headers before the loop then add the content with the loop.

for example:

```
Datatable.AddSheet("Emp_name")
Datatable.GetSheet("Emp_name").AddParameter "Emp_first_Name",""
Datatable.GetSheet("Emp_name").AddParameter "EMP_Last_Name",""

For i = 1 To 2 Step 1
    datatable.SetCurrentRow(i)  
    
    Dim f_name,l_name
    f_name="hello"
    l_name="world"
    
    Datatable.GetSheet("Emp_name").SetCurrentRow i
    Datatable.Value("Emp_first_Name", "Emp_name") = f_name
    Datatable.Value("EMP_Last_Name", "Emp_name") = l_name

Next
```

Output looks like this:

[image: UFT output]